# I can't to set the Customer parameter correctly in Entity of JournalEntryLineDetail in quickbooks/v3-php-sdk?

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I sent next object:

```json
{
    "TxnDate": "2020-05-05",
    "DocNumber": "Test123",
    "Line": [{
        "Description": "Test FBA Fees",
        "Amount": 100,
        "DetailType": "JournalEntryLineDetail",
        "JournalEntryLineDetail": {
            "PostingType": "Credit",
            "Entity": {
                "Type": "Customer",
                "EntityRef": {
                    "value": 1
                }
            },
            "AccountRef": {
                "value": 128
            }
        }
    }, {
        "Description": "Test",
        "Amount": 100,
        "DetailType": "JournalEntryLineDetail",
        "JournalEntryLineDetail": {
            "PostingType": "Debit",
            "AccountRef": {
                "value": 52
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

but received error message:

`Passed array has no key for 'Value' when contructing an ReferenceType`.

Please, tell me what is wrong with my request?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JournalEntryEntity` instead of `Entity` under `JournalEntryLineDetail`, like so:

```json
{
    "TxnDate": "2020-05-05",
    "DocNumber": "Test123",
    "Line": [{
        "Description": "Test FBA Fees",
        "Amount": 100,
        "DetailType": "JournalEntryLineDetail",
        "JournalEntryLineDetail": {
            "PostingType": "Credit",
            "JournalEntryEntity": {
                "Type": "Customer",
                "EntityRef": {
                    "value": 1
                }
            },
            "AccountRef": {
                "value": 128
            }
        }
    }, {
        "Description": "Test",
        "Amount": 100,
        "DetailType": "JournalEntryLineDetail",
        "JournalEntryLineDetail": {
            "PostingType": "Debit",
            "AccountRef": {
                "value": 52
            }
        }
    }]
}
```